# Custom ArrayAdapter without custom item data-type

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I try to implement a `ListView` with specific icon, title and subtitle at each item. 
The data of all items is in an `ArrayList` of objects from following `class`:

```
class ItemObject{
    String title="";
    String subTitle="";
    String unit="";
    int icon;
    int quantity;
    int parentID;
    int orderInList;
}

ArrayList<ItemObject> listViewData;
```

Here is the code I used first:

```
class ExtendedArrayAdapter<String> extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private Context context;
    private String[] items;

    public ExtendedArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] items){
        super(context,-1,items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items=items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_item_bg,parent,false);
        TextView itemTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        TextView itemSubTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemSubTitle);
        ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon);

        itemTitle.setText(listViewData.get(position).title);
        itemSubTitle.setText(listViewData.get(position).subTitle);
        itemIcon.setBackgroundResource(listViewData.get(position).icon);
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

But the problem regarding this custom ArrayAdapter is that `ExtendedArrayAdapter` needs a `String[]` of `items` to get the number of `ListView` items.

**Question:**
Is it possible to change the `ExtendedArrayAdapter` class to get directly the length of `ListView` instead of `String[] items`?

**EDIT1:**
In `super()`, I can use only following set of parameters: 
[image]

and all need `Array<String>` or `List<String>`. So I cannot use my ArrayList of objects here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the ExtendedArrayAdapter class to get
>   directly the length of ListView instead of String[] items?

the length of the `ListView` in terms of item it is handling, is given from `Adapter.getCount()`. The answer to your question, if I understand it correctly, is then no. The definition of your Adapter should change like

```
class ExtendedArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemObject>{
```

you will have to change the `constructor` and the type of `items` as well

Comment: if I remove `String[] items` from `constructor`, and consequently from `super(context,-1,items);`, an empty `ListView` is shown

Comment: not removing. You have to change it in either ItemObject[] or List< ItemObject>

Comment: please have a look at <b>EDIT1</b>

Comment: did you change the declaration of ExtendedArrayAdapter like: `class ExtendedArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemObject>{` ?